# Is my proof that $\sqrt{6} \notin \mathbb{Q}$ correct?

Tags: analysis

We will attempt a proof by contradiction.
Assume there exists two integers $p$ and $q$ such that $\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^2 =64$.
Hence, $p^2 = 6 \cdot q^2$.
Thus, $6 | p$ and $3 | p$.
Let $3 \cdot r=p$, where $r$ is an integer. Then, $9 \cdot r^2=6 \cdot q^2$.
Thus, $q^2=\frac{3}{2}\cdot r^2$.
Suppose $r =5$. Then, $q^2=37.5$.

Therefore, $q$ cannot be an integer, which is in contradiction with the original statement.

Note: very new to proofs (2nd one) so apologies for bad formatting etc.

Comment: 'Suppose $r=5$' is not correct.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

Good $2$nd attempt at a proof but unfortunately you are missing the mark slightly. Let me rewrite your proof with corrections:

We will attempt a proof by contradiction.
Assume there exists integers $p,q$ such that $(p/q)^2 =6$ **and $\text{gcd}(p,q)=1$**.

*Note that any fraction can be written in most simplified form and in fact this fact is critical for the contradiction you are trying to arrive at*

Therefore $p^2 = 6q^2$.
Therefore p divisible by $6$ and $p$ divisible by $3$.
Let $3r=p$,where $r$ is an integer:
$9r^2=6q^2$.

---

**This section does not lead to a contradiction, even if everything except the last statement is true**

Therefore $q^2=3/2(r^2)$.
Suppose $r =5$:
therefore $q^2=37.5$.
Therefore Q cannot be an integer, which is in contradiction with original statement.

---

**Instead, write**

Divide both sides by $3$ to get $3r^2=2q^2$. Since $3$ does not divide $2$, $3$ must divide $q$.

*Do you see why this is the case?*

But this is a contradiction since $\text{gcd}(q,p)\geq 3$.